# NSConstraint based on a frame size

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have a view controller which has a view with a height constraint. Such view controller is called from another view controller which its view doesn't occupy the whole screen height. 
I want to set the height constraint based on the first view height, how can I make this conversion?

Comment: provide an image to be more clearier

Comment: How are the first controller's view and the windows related? Is it inside a container or is the root on the active window?